# programmatically add multiple jupyter notebook cells with plotly graph and an input cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to programmatically add a plotly graph in one cell followed by an input cell. The desired output is as follows (Graph in one cell, input on another):

[image: Graph]
[image: Input Box]

[image: Graph]
[image: Input Box]

With `get_ipython().set_next_input("Error Description: ")` I'm able to add the input box but I can't use the same for the plotly `fig.show()` method. Instead, what happens when I'm plotting more than one graph is that it plots all the graphs in one cell and only then adds the input box (like shown in the next image).

[image: Graph]
[image: Graph]
[image: Input Box]

I don't really know if providing a minimum reproducible code even helps because it is just a for loop (iterating *n* times, where *n* is the number of graphs I want plotted). In this example only 2 graphs are ploted and they are exactly the same but on my use case I'm plotting 40 graphs and I need 40 input boxes so that I can add some comments to each. If it helps the code is provided next (the `plot_graph()` method only shows one graph when called):

```
#Plot the graphs and add a description cell
for indv_error in range(len(error_code)):
   plot_graph(df)  #Inside this method I tried the 'set_next_input' on the fig.show()
   get_ipython().set_next_input("Error Description: ")
```

Thank you.